# Multivariate Newton-Raphson method and FindRoot module

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, iterators

Let's suppose that we have the following equation

```
Clear["Global`*"];

m = 1/2;
V = m/Sqrt[(x - m)^2 + (y - m)^2 + (z - m)^2] + m/Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + (y + m)^2 + (z + m)^2] 
+ 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);

Vx = D[V, x];
Vy = D[V, y];
Vz = D[V, z];
```

Then we can use the `FindRoot` module for finding a solution of the system $Vx = Vy = Vz = 0$ with initial conditions $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,1,1)$.

```
sol = Module[{s = 0, e = 0}, {FindRoot[{Vx == 0, Vy == 0, Vz == 0}, 
 {{x, 1}, {y, 1}, {z, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
 StepMonitor :> s++, EvaluationMonitor :> e++],
 "Steps" -> s, "Evaluations" -> e}]
```

The results is

> {{x -> 0.9466454951651958, y -> 0.9466454951651958, 
>     z -> 0.4788183020073119}, "Steps" -> 7, "Evaluations" -> 9}

Now I want to obtain the same result but using my own version of the numerical Newton-Raphson iterator, according to these [notes](http://www.mediafire.com/file/l3d5yr2ger9qvvy/sys_3x3.pdf/file).

```
Vxx = D[Vx, x];
Vxy = D[Vx, y];
Vxz = D[Vx, z];

Vyx = D[Vy, x];
Vyy = D[Vy, y];
Vyz = D[Vz, z];

Vzx = D[Vz, x];
Vzy = D[Vz, y];
Vzz = D[Vz, z];

ff = Vx;
gg = Vy;
hh = Vz;

fx = Vxx;
fy = Vxy;
fz = Vxz;
gx = Vyx;
gy = Vyy;
gz = Vyz;
hx = Vzx;
hy = Vzy;
hz = Vzz;

J11 = gy*hz - hy*gz;
J12 = hx*gz - gx*hz;
J13 = gx*hy - hx*gy;
J21 = hy*fz - fy*hz;
J22 = fx*hz - hx*fz;
J23 = hx*fy - fx*hy;
J31 = fx*gz - gy*fz;
J32 = gx*fz - fx*gz;
J33 = fx*gy - gx*fy; 

det = fx*J11 + fy*J12 + fz*J13;

Nx = ff*J11 + gg*J21 + hh*J31;
Ny = ff*J12 + gg*J22 + hh*J32;
Nz = ff*J13 + gg*J23 + hh*J33;

x0 = 1.;
y0 = 1.;
z0 = 1.;

tol = 10^-15;
n = 20;
iter0 = 0;

Do[
  iter = iter0 + i;
  Nx0 = Nx /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, z -> z0};
  Ny0 = Ny /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, z -> z0};
  Nz0 = Nz /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, z -> z0};
  det0 = det /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, z -> z0};
  x1 = x0 - Nx0/det0;
  y1 = y0 - Ny0/det0;
  z1 = z0 - Nz0/det0;
  dx = Abs[x1 - x0];
  dy = Abs[y1 - y0];
  dz = Abs[z1 - z0];
  Print["i = ", iter, ",  x1 = ", NumberForm[x1, 16], ",  y1 = ", 
  NumberForm[y1, 16], ",  z1 = ", NumberForm[z1, 16]];
  If[Abs[x1 - x0] < tol && Abs[y1 - y0] < tol && 
  Abs[z1 - z0] < tol, {Print["The method converges"], Exit[]}];
  x0 = x1;
  y0 = y1;
  z0 = z1;
 , {i, 1, n}
];
```

As you can see, the iterative method diverges and does not provide the results given by `FindRoot`.

So my question is: Is there any mistake in the implementation of the iterative scheme? Why it fails to provide the same results as `FindRoot`?

**NOTE:** For other systems of equations the result of the iterator coincides with that of `FindRoot`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while the question is certainly important to the OP, it is unlikely to be of value to someone else.  My understanding is that this site is not meant for debugging code that attempts to duplicate existing *Mathematica* functions.

Comment: Even if your implementation of the inverse of the Jacobian is correct, the method may be still divergent for not-so-nice initial points. Usually, adding a line search can enlarge of the set of "good" initial points tremendously. Btw.: Why don't you use vectors and matrices (and functions instead of `/.`)?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Next you'll be asking why not use `Det[]`, or what's the point of the 10th through 21st lines of code in the second code-block, or `Print[]`, or `Exit[]` of all things (inside a list no less).... :)  It's clearly likely a line-by-line translation of C-like code.  Perhaps the OP wants it corrected before refactoring.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, you're probably right...

Comment: Try `x0 = 1.;
y0 = 1.;
z0 = 1./2;`  The original starting point diverges, which, as is well known, can happen with Newton's method.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But why for the starting point (1,1,1) `FindRoot` converges to a root, while my method diverges? This is what I want to know.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As I've already mentioned: `FindRoot` applies **line search**.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What do you mean by the term "line search"? Could you please briefly explain it?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z `FindRoot` *does not* converge for initial point `{1,1,1}`. Haven't you seen the error message?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Using   sol = Module[{s = 0, e = 0}, {FindRoot[{Vx == 0, Vy == 0, Vz == 0}, 
 {{x, 1}, {y, 1}, {z, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
 StepMonitor :> s++, EvaluationMonitor :> e++],
 "Steps" -> s, "Evaluations" -> e}]    for initial point (1,1,1) I get the result  {{x -> 0.9466454951651958, y -> 0.9466454951651958, z -> 0.4788183020073119}, "Steps" -> 7, "Evaluations" -> 9}, which means that `FindRoot` converges for (1,1,1).

Comment: Then your question is really about `FindRoot`, which, according to the tutorial, does not use a pure Newton's method, but a damped one with step control.  Try `FindRoot` with `Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Finally thank you! Any suggestions on how to insert step control in my custom iterative scheme which is the classical Newton method?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodRoot.html) has links to descriptions of the `"LineSearch"` and `"TrustRegion"` step-control methods.  They may contain enough information for you to write your own.  I've never tried, but just use `FindRoot` instead.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
V = m/Sqrt[(x - m)^2 + (y - m)^2 + (z - m)^2] + 
    m/Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + (y + m)^2 + (z + m)^2] + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);
```

The system

$$
V_x = 0\\
V_y = 0\\
V_z = 0
$$

has notoriously three solutions which are for $m = \frac 13$

$$
X_a\left(\frac 13\right) = \{0.751246,0.751246,0.304505\}\ \ \ \mbox{or}\ \ \ X_b=\{0,0,0\}
$$

For $X_0 > m\{1,1,1\}$ the iterative procedure converges to $X_a(m)$ If  $X_0 < -m\{1,1,1\}$ converges to $-X_a(m)$ otherwise converges to $X_b$

Follows a very basic script which shows this fact.

```
X = {x, y, z};
alpha = m + 0.1;
minerror = 10^-10;
grad = Grad[V, X];
f = grad;
H = Grad[f, X];
iH = Inverse[H];
X0 = alpha {1., 1., 1.};

For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++,
    iH0 = iH /. Thread[X -> X0];
    f0 = f /. Thread[X -> X0];
    error = Max[Abs[f0]];
    Print[i, " " , X0, " ", error];
    If[error < minerror, Break[]];
    X1 = X0 - iH0.f0;
    X0 = X1
]
```

Resuming, the iterative process converges to $X_a(m)$ when $X_0 > m\{1,1,1\}$. If $X_0 < -m\{1,1,1\}$ converges to $-X_a(m)$, otherwise, converges to $X_b$

NOTE

The iterative process can be described as

$$
X_{k+1} = X_k - H_k^{-1}\cdot \nabla V_k
$$

where $X = \{x,y,z\},\ \ H = \nabla^2 V$

Attached the three solutions for $m=\frac 12$. In light red $V_x = 0$ in light green $V_y = 0$ and in light yellow $V_z = 0$
[image]

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I want the solution of the system for m =1/2 not 1/3. Moreover, I am asking why the custom iterative scheme diverges..

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Please. Substitute in the script  m=1/2 and it will converge to  $X_a(1/2) = \{0.946645,0.946645,0.478818\}$

Comment: OK but again I need to know why my custom iterative scheme does not converge to the same root. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Having MATHEMATICA with all it's symbolic processing power, the most indicated practice is to use this power to avoid transcription errors that may arise when manipulating formulas obtained with intermediate steps as could be the case with your script.

Answer (score 0):

The iterates of Newton's method for the equation $F(x) = 0$ with a initial guess $x_0$ look like
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - DF(x_k)^{-1} \, F(x_k).$$ 
If $x_0$ is chosen badly, then there may happen large jumps $x_{k+1} - x_k$, so large that you can easily miss the basin of attraction.

One can remedy this by a picking an appropriate step size $0 < \tau_k \leq 1$  and use the iterates
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \tau_k \, DF(x_k)^{-1} \, F(x_k).$$

Choosing a fixed $\tau_k = q$ with $0< q< 1$ is often referred to as *damped Newton method*. Alas, this slows down the convergence rate from $q$-quadratic convergence to only $q$-linear convergence (if I recall correctly).

*Line search methods* try to automize the choice of $\tau_k$ in such a way that one obtains $\tau_k \approx 1$ if $x_k$ is close to a solution in order to obtain optimal convergence rate.

*Armijo line search* (also called *backtracking line search*) applies the following strategy: It beliefs that the *search direction* $u_k = - DF(x_k)^{-1} \, F(x_k)$ is already good and picks $\tau_k$ such that a certain *merit function* $\varphi \colon [0,\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is *sufficiently reduced* in the sense that $$\varphi(\tau_k) < \varphi(0) - \sigma \varphi'(0) \, \tau_k$$ with some parameter $\sigma \in ]0,1[$.

If one applies Newton's method for minimization, i.e., if one tries to solve the equation $Df(x)=0$ with a given objective function $f$, then one usually choses the merit function as $\varphi(t) = f(x_k + t \, u_k)$. Then one starts with an initial guess $t$ for $\tau_k$, say $t = 1$, checks whether $$\varphi(t) < \varphi(0) - \sigma \varphi'(0) \, t$$ is fulfilled: If it is fulfilled, one choose $\tau_k = 1$; otherwise, one scales $t$ down (i.e. $t \leftarrow \gamma \, t$ with some $0<\gamma<1$) and tries again... until one finds a $t$ satisfying the inequality. If $f$ is sufficiently smooth, existence of such a $t$ is guaranteed.

For general equations $F(x) = 0$, this won't work since there is no function $f$. Then one may use the merit function $\varphi(t) = \|F(x_k + t\, u_k)\|^2$. Notice that $\varphi'(0) = 2 \langle F(x_k) , DF(x_k) \, u_k \rangle = -2 \|F(x_k)\|^2$, so that we obtain the following as condition of sufficient reduce of the merit function:
$$\|F(x_k + t \, u_k)\|^2 < \|F(x_k)\|^2 (1- 2 \, \sigma \, t).$$
In fact, this can be satisfied only if $\sigma < \frac{1}{2}$. In practice, $\sigma$ can be chosen rather small; often $\sigma = \frac{1}{1000}$ and $\gamma = \frac{1}{4}$ work quite fine. This basically ensures $\|F(x_{k+1})\|^2 < \|F(x_k)\|^2$ which is fairly reasonable because we want to minimize $\|F(x)\|^2$. Since we want maximal convergence rate when $x_k$ is close to a solution, we should always use $t = 1$ as initial guess for $\tau_k$.